# Getting an error if I install torch and trasformers using poetry. The error is related with libcupti.so.11.7

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, torch, python-poetry

I have added and installed torch and transformer using poetry, but when I import transformer I obtain this error:
`RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.pipelines because of the following error (look up to see its traceback): libcupti.so.11.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

The error solves automatically if I reinstall torch with pip. This is probably a problem of poetry. Do someone know how to solve it?

Reinstall torch with pip and it works